# Как преобразовать строку в дату php?

Tags: php, дата, строки

Имеется переменная `$date` - она строка! Дата в ней записана в формате `2013-06-17 19:00:00` нужно преобразовать в дату ее пробовал так

```
function dateToTime($datenow2) {
    return strtotime("$datenow2 GMT");
}
```

`echo gettype($datenow2);` - все равно выдает что строка она (что не так, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: LOL а что должен выдать? [object Date]?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, ТС пытается привести строку к новому типу данных (date)?

Так вот, типов данных в PHP восемь:

Скалярные (простые) типы:

- строки
- целые числа (int)
- double (или float, числа с плавающей
     точкой)
- boolean (логический тип)

Смешанные типы:

- массивы
- объекты

И 2 специальных типа:

- ресурсы
- NULL

Типа Date не существует, а потому не понятно, что же вы хотите получить, а главное, зачем?

Answer (score 11):

```
$date = "2013-06-17 19:00:00";
$d1 = strtotime($date); // переводит из строки в дату
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", $d1); // переводит в новый формат
```

Answer (score 0):

А результат dateToTime ты какой переменной присваиваешь? :)

Следующий вариант работает:

```
$date = '2013-06-17 19:00:00';
$datenow2 = strtotime("$date GMT");
echo $datenow2.' - '.gettype($datenow2);
```

Выведет: 1371495600 - integer

Answer (score 0):

```php
/*      функция конвертации даты из yyyy-mm-dd в dd-mm-yyyy     */
function dateFormat(date) {
    var dateout = date.split('-')[2] + '-' + date.split('-')[1] + '-' + date.split('-')[0]; // конвертируем дату из yyyy-mm-dd в dd-mm-yyyy
    return dateout;
}
```