# Как преобразование строки в дату на примере?

Tags: php, битрикс

Приветствую. Мне необходимо перевести из строки в дату переменную. Ниже сам код...

```
$arFilter = array("ID" => 16104);
$arSelect = array('NAME', 'PROPERTY_PAR_ID', 'PROPERTY_P_DATE', 'PROPERTY_P_NUMBER',
    'PROPERTY_P_GIVER', 'PROPERTY_PAR_ID', 'PROPERTY_STATUS', 'ID', 'DATE_ACTIVE_FROM',
    'DATE_ACTIVE_TO', 'DATE_CREATE', 'PROPERTY_DATE_IN', 'PROPERTY_DATE_OUT', 'PROPERTY_TYPE', 
    'PROPERTY_AUTHOR', 'PROPERTY_RESP_USER', 'PROPERTY_P_IS_ONETIME');
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
$res = $res->Fetch();
$canget = true; 

if($res['DATE_ACTIVE_TO'] < date('d.m.Y H:i')) {
    $canget = false;
    }else{};

echo gettype(date($res['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']));
echo "\n";
echo date('d.m.Y H:i');
```

на выходе я получаю следующее:

string
14.11.2017 11:08

Подскажите пожалуйста, что необходимо написать? Пробовал вариант из статьи [Как преобразовать строку в дату php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229226/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-php)
К сожалению на моём варианте он не отработал почему-то....

Comment: `echo $res['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы преобразовать строку в timestamp можно воспользоваться функцией [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php), а функция [time](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) вернет текущий timestamp.

Скорее всего, сравнение вам надо делать таким образом

```
if(strtotime($res['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']) < time()) {
```

Функция [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) нужна для преобразования timestamp'a в символьно представление

Comment: Да, вы оказались прав. Приведение не к дате, а к времени.

Comment: в моём примере участвует страничка для пропусков, и DATE_ACTIVE_TO - дата и время по которую активен этот пропуск. Но бывают случаи когда допустим бронировали на 11 утра и пришли к 11:01. Преобразовал вашу конструкцию так:
if(strtotime("+3 hours", strtotime($res['DATE_ACTIVE_TO'])) < time()) {

Однако нужно тогда ограничить концом дня для DATE_ACTIVE_TO... не подскажите как прописать конец дня?

Comment: `strtotime('midnight')` - полночь

Comment: `strtomite(date('Y-m-d') . '  18:00')` -  соответственно 18 часов сегодня

Comment: Благодарю вас за вашу помощь!

Comment: Рад, что помог. Удачи вам!